# Is my motherboard RAM slot defective?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have Intel S1200V3RPS motherboard. I bought it in September 2014 and was using 2x8GB RAMs in the first two slots till now. Last week, I decided to upgrade RAM on my server and bought two additional RAM sticks of the same model and make by the same company (Kingston). But the additional two slots do not appear to be working.

Following things work:
1) Two old sticks in slots 1 & 2 work fine.
2) Two new sticks in slots 1 & 2 work fine.
3) One old and one new stick in slots 1 & 2 work fine.
4) Each of the 4 sticks work individually in either slot 1 or slot 2.
From above 4 points, it appears that the RAM sticks are fine and they are compatible with each other.

Now, if I put any stick in slot 3 or 4 (irrespective of whether there are any sticks in slots 1 & 2), the computer refuses to start. When I press the power button, there are 3 beeps and then nothing happens. Now, I wonder if slots 3 and 4 on the motherboard are bad. This is an assembled server and I have made the wire connections. Can somebody tell me if I may have missed some wire connections so that RAM slots 3 & 4 are not working? Any other troubleshooting will also help.

I am using Intel Xeon 1230v3 processor and Kingston KVR16LE11/8i RAM modules.

(I have contacted Intel Customer Support and their only option is to send the product to their service center where they would check the problem and send a replacement. But this solution does not work for me as I have only one server and the solution of Intel will mean downtime of atleast 3 weeks.)

Comment: The motherboard manual will usually have a beep code listing, which will tell you what the motherboard is trying to tell you. Maybe that really is "bad RAM", but maybe it is something else. I suggest you dig out the manual and look that up. Also, you seem to be confusing "server" and "workstation"; might want to [edit] to use only either one as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I have updated the post to list only server. I'll check the motherboard manual.

Comment: I have checked the motherboard manual and I cannot find any troubleshooting information based on sound beeps.

Comment: Check online....

Comment: If the only new memory works by itself and the old memory works by itself.  If the new and old memory work in combination.  The only thing that tells me is the 2nd memory channel on your motherboard is not working.

Comment: @Ramhound, Is there any way to fix this 2nd memory channel?

Comment: @amitchaudhary - You send your defective motherboard to Intel and they send you a replacement motherboard if they determine it is indeed defective.  If the second memory channel, indeed not working ( and your problem isn't caused by user error ), there isn't much you can do as the end user except replace the motherboard.

Comment: @Ramhound, I was hoping to avoid this. I'll keep the 16 GB configuration for now if it means possible downtime of atleast 3 weeks. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You should be more specific which slots you are talking about. The board's slots are labelled A1, A2, B1, B2. "1 2 3 4" is ambiguous.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq, A_1 and A_2 are working fine, B_1 and B_2 are the problematic ones. Please let me know if this helps with some other resolution.

Comment: OK, that would confirm the memory channel theory.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq, does that mean the problem is most probably with the motherboard when you say it confirms the memory channel theory. Pardon me as I am not very familiar with these terms.

Comment: No, the memory channels are on your processor. It could be either the processor or the motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motherboard docs[1] say that three beeps indicates a fatal error related to memory. This means that the RAM slots are probably bad (:(). Sorry, but you'll probably have to send it in to have the motherboard repaired.

[1] http://www.manualslib.com/manual/708923/Intel-S1200v3rp.html?page=264, the official manual for the Intel S1200V3RPS.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the manual. Appears nothing I can do to fix it.

Comment: It's just as possible that the processor is bad, not the motherboard or slots, because the memory controller is in the processor.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq, is there a way to check if the problem is with processor or motherboard slots. Please note that I do not have any spare components.

Comment: @amitchaudhary Only by swapping a different processor in.